# hunspell spell check

Tags: c#, .net, c++, spell-checking, hunspell

I had a specific question regrading ordering the suggested words returned by hunspell on a typo. The words seems to be returned in an alpha order. I want to order the suggestions by relevance, that is the closest match should show up first.
I couldn't find any way to do that via hunspell apis. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

You're not putting the results into a sorted list or anything like that, are you?

When I call `int iCount = pHunspell->suggest(aSuggestions, "Testig")` I get "Testing, Testis, Testes".  If it was in alphabetical order, "Testes" would have been first, which is certainly *not* what I had intended.

Tested in unmanaged C++ with versions 1.2.2 and 1.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with above. Hunspell makes use of certain probability models like keyboard character proximities and phonetic similarities to suggest best matches. You must be storing it in a list which gets sorted.